# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, tuples, attributeerror

I have a homework assignment for a Python class and am running into an error that I don't understand. Running Python IDLE v3.2.2 on Windows 7.

Below is where the problem is happening:

```
#local variables
number=0
item=''
cost=''

#prompt user how many entries
number=int(input('\nHow many items to add?: '))

#open file
openfile=('test.txt','w')

#starts for loop to write new lines
for count in range(1,number+1):
    print('\nFor item #',count,'.',sep='')
    item=input('Name:  ')
    cost=float(input('Cost: $'))

    #write to file
    openfile.write(item+'\n')
    openfile.write(cost+'\n')

#Display message and closes file
print('Records written to test.txt.',sep='')
openfile.close
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "I:\Cent 110\test.py", line 19, in openfile.write(item+'\n')
>   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: You should check out the [``with`` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files - it means you don't have to manually close them, and works correctly even under exceptions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the [open](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#open).

```
openfile = open('test.txt','w')
```

And at the end there are missing parens when you try to close the file

```
openfile.close()
```

*Edit*: I just saw another problem.

```
openfile.write(str(cost)+'\n')
```

Comment: openfile=open('test.txt','w') is there. Thanks tho :)

Comment: Thanks for catching the end parenthesis. Completely missed it. However, that didn't fix my problem. :(

Comment: @dhc: you *are* missing the open. Look again at your code. This is trivial to spot - the interpreter tells you what line the error appears in. All you have to do is ask yourself "what is `openfile`, and why doesn't it have a `write` attribute?". To do that, look (closely!) at where you define `openfile`. You'll see you're missing the open statement.